Cypress test case . Finding a specific table cell value that is almost similar to others
The subject is a Cypress test case on the basis of JavaScript.
I have a problem finding the exact row for a specific sum in a table. In this case sum 2. The string is lmost similar to others.
My problem if searching for the table cell value of "sum 2" my script finds the first entry with "sum 2" which is in fact "sum 2 abc".
I have found reg exp examples but do not know how to integrate it into my code:
// string.match(/^abc$/)

Here my code in javascript:
let valueArray_amount = [];

for (let i = 2; i <= 15; i++) {
    cy.get('.tabele1 > tbody > tr.tabele_row3 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, index, $list) => {
      var titletext = $e1.text();

      // Tabele column title left from JSON file
      cy.fixture('nameOfJSONfile').then(name => {
        const categoryheadline = name[35].column1string_ABC
      
        cy.wrap(null).then(() => {

          if (titletext.includes(categoryheadline)) {
          
            cy.get(`.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(${i})`).eq(index).then(function(amount) {
              // Save the value amount in array
              valueArray_amount.push(amount.text().trim());


             
      // Check if all complete before adding global array
              // 14 columns -> 12 months plus two additional columns
              if (valueArray_amount.length === (14)) {

                // Save value in global array
                globalArray_amount = valueArray_amount;
              }
            });
          }

        }) // wrap

      })
    });
  }

I need specificly for "categoryheadline" the exact regular expression. How can I solve this?
This part does not work:
if (titletext.includes(categoryheadline)) {

I tried for example with match(^${tableheadline}$) but it does not work. That const tableheadline would have the value "sum 2" so that is the place for reg ex I think.
Does someone has any idea?
Thank you

Not sure, but you might try it with the RegExp() constructor instead.

You probably don't need a regex for the exact match since javascript === operator is performing an exact match.
These are the changes I would try
cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(1)')
  .each(($e1, index, $list) => {

    const titletext = $e1.text().trim();  // add trim to be safe

    cy.fixture('nameOfJSONfile').then(name => {
      const categoryheadline = name[35].column1string_ABC
      
      if (titletext === categoryheadline) {
        cy.get(`.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(${index})`)
          .then(...

Maybe you can avoid the if() by using a filter on the table query (since there is no else part).
cy.fixture('nameOfJSONfile').then(name => {
  const categoryheadline = name[35].column1string_ABC

  cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(1)')
    .should('have.text', categoryheadline)
    .each(($e1, index, $list) => {

      cy.get(`.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(${index})`)
        .then(...

